# Return 410 gone status code for URLs containing same characters in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, 410-gone

My website was hit by the pharma spam attack which created hundreds of URLs, all of which contain the last 5 characters `-1234.pdf`.

So that Google and other search engines will remove these quicker, I'd like to return these pages with a 410/GONE status code, is there an easier way of doing this in `.htaccess` other than listing all of the URLs and setting `RewriteRule`s for every single one (a process which would take considerable hours!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve a 410 Gone for all URLs that end in the literal string `-1234.pdf` then you can use the following mod_rewrite directive at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule -1234\.pdf$ - [G]
```

Or to reject any URL that ends in `-NNNN.pdf` where `NNNN` is a number of at least 4 digits then you can change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to something like: `-\d{4,}\.pdf$`.

> but the URLs are still returning a 404.

In the case where the server has defined a custom 410 ErrorDocument and is overriding the HTTP response code then set the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file (make sure you've not defined a custom 410 `ErrorDocument` yourself later in the `.htaccess` file or server config):

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

---

> **UPDATE:** we also have some other spammy URLs which have the string "stmap_9874100.html" (where the last three digits are always different), can a similar query be written to set these URLs to 410's too?

Yes, you can add another directive similar to before:

```
RewriteRule stmap_9874\d{3}\.html$ - [G]
```

Explanation of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex / Regular Expression) and directive:

- `stmap_9874` - These characters are matched literally (anywhere in the URL-path).
- `\d` is a shorthand character class representing any digit (0-9) and `\d{3}` is exactly 3 of them.
- `\.` matches a literal dot, otherwise, a dot in regex matches *any character* (except newlines).
- `html` - These characters are matched literally.
- `$` is an "anchor" that represents the end of the string. So this string of characters must occur at the end of the URL-path.
- `-` (hyphen) - not part of the regex, this is the second argument to the `RewriteRule` directive. This is just a "placeholder" indicating *no substitution*. The URL is not rewritten/redirected to anything else.
- The `G` flag (short for `R=410`) results in a 410 Gone response. (The `L` flag is not required here, as it is implied when specifying a response code out of the 3xx (and 2xx) range.)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, I just have tried this out and inserted the above mod_rewrite directive as suggested at the top of the .htaccess file but the URLs are still returning a 404. I have cleared my cache and double checked I have the directive correct! Can you help?

Comment: Can you post an actual URL you are trying to catch? Do you have other directives in `.htaccess`? Also make sure that your server is not configured to send 404 instead of 410 (for instance, if there is a custom 410 ErrorDocument defined somewhere).

Comment: The URL is usually a string of text, eg domain.com/wwwmedridnet-1234.pdf but the string of text is random, it is only the preceding 5 characters/digits that are identical

In terms of other directives, I have Wordpress: 

        # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

Alongside that, rewrite rules to block fake referral traffic; 301 redirects for older pages & IP blocking

Comment: Please edit your question to include your entire `.htaccess` file. The only reasons why this directive wouldn't work are... either: **#1** The request doesn't actually end `-1234.pdf`. **#2** There is a conflict with existing directives (do you have any mod_alias `Redirect` and/or `RedirectMatch` directives)? **#3** The server is configured to return a 404 instead of a 410 (in the case of a custom ErrorDocument being defined).

Comment: I've updated my answer with regards to #3 - if a custom error document is overriding the HTTP response code.

Comment: Glad that resolved the issue. If you can mark the answer as "accepted" it will remove the question from the unanswered question queue and help others. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hello, I have just found we also have some other spammy URLs which have the string "stmap_9874100.html" (where the last three digits are always different), can a similar query be written to set these URLs to 410's too?

Comment: @Sam Yes you can add another directive. I assume this string appears at the end of the URL-path as before? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Apologies, one final question! I've been using Wordfence and monitoring live traffic. Googlebot is trying to crawl the URLs sometimes with less than 3 characters (i.e. stmap_98740.html). I have fixed this by editing the expression \d{3} to \d{1,3} which has done the trick. In another case, a string of random text which precedes the URL, /stmap_98740.html%3Ffincar.levitra.nimodipine.menosan, however %3F is not converted by the bot to a "?" and so the URL returns a 404. Can I get it to also include any other characters AFTER the ".html". Thank you in advance!

Comment: "fixed this by editing the expression `\d{3}` to `\d{1,3}`" - looks OK - so the string can end in 1 to 3 random digits. "include any other characters AFTER the `.html`" - just remove the trailing `$` on the regex. To catch any _URL-path_ that contains a literal `?` (ie. the `?` is URL encoded as `%3F`, so it's not the query string) then you can do something like: `RewriteRule \? - [G]`. The RewriteRule pattern matches against the %-decoded URL-path, so it matches a literal `?` (not `%3F`). However, depending on where the `%3F` appears in the URL, the server may trigger a 403.